# Outputcache breaks Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm using `WebEssentials.AspNetCore.OutputCaching` to cache my webpages. I set this cache to about 12 hours because for example the homepage doesn't refresh a lot, but it can be a slow process to load everything initially.

However if I add this cache and check my website 10 minutes later, I see the following error in the console:

```
The list of component records is not valid
```

This is an error outputted by Blazor, and all Blazor components stop working. Is there a way to fix this?

I've read [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26174) that the Blazor component descriptors encode a timeout of 5 minutes. I assume this is the reason. Can this timeout value be changed? Is there a workaround when working with cache?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blazor: The list of component records is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60125243/blazor-the-list-of-component-records-is-not-valid)

Comment: No not really, that an entirely different problem.